# Add LogCat logs to Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I'm using Firebase Crashlytics to report crashes. I'm using a game framework that handles logging for me and when running on Android, it logs to LogCat. I want to be able to include the LogCat logs with the crash report in Crashlytics. Is this possible?

I found this Library that could help (https://github.com/Ereza/LogcatReporter), but I'm not sure how well supported it is.

I know I can log like this:

```
FirebaseCrashlytics crashlytics = FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance();

crashlytics.log("my message");
crashlytics.log("E/TAG: my message");
```

But I would prefer for the framework I'm using to handle the logging.

Any way to include those LogCat logs? Does Firebase have a built in supported way?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there is no feature to save logs into `Firebase Crashlytics`, but I found an interesting [solution](https://proandroiddev.com/remote-logging-with-timber-and-firebase-realtime-database-a9dfbe66284c) for saving logs into `Firebase Realtime Database`.